# Scala method cannot resolve variable

Tags: scala

I'm just getting started with Scala and trying to write a method that removes a pair of parentheses from a list of characters.

```
def removePairOfBrackets(chars: List[Char]): List[Char] =
  val firstOpeningBracket: Int = chars.indexOf('(')
  val firstClosingBracket: Int = chars.indexOf(')')
  if (firstOpeningBracket > firstClosingBracket) chars
  else
  chars.patch(firstOpeningBracket, Nil, 1).patch(firstClosingBracket - 1, Nil, 1)
```

In the second line of this method I get the message that:

```
Cannot resolve symbol chars
```

Comment: Hint: there is no second line of your "function" (which is actually a method, not a function, a function is something completely different in Scala). It has only one line.

Comment: Ah - curly brackets. Knew it was something simple :). Many thanks!

Comment: FYI, this will remove, quite literally, the first set of brackets found, but will not properly remove the **matching set** unless there is only one pair. Ex: `(2+(3+4)*5)` -> `2+(3+4*5)` instead of `2+(3+4)*5`

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method had no 'body' - adding curly brackets fixed it.

```
def removePairOfBrackets(chars: List[Char]): List[Char] = {
  val firstOpeningBracket: Int = chars.indexOf('(')
  val firstClosingBracket: Int = chars.indexOf(')')
  if (firstOpeningBracket > firstClosingBracket) chars
  else
    chars.patch(firstOpeningBracket, Nil, 1).patch(firstClosingBracket - 1, Nil, 1)
}
```

Comment: please approve your answer, so no other solution will be submitted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this instead: 

  chars.mkString.replaceFirst("\\(","").replaceFirst("\\)","").toList
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val chars = List('a','b','(','c','(','d',')','e','(',')')
chars: List[Char] = List(a, b, (, c, (, d, ), e, (, ))

scala> chars.mkString.replaceFirst("\\(","").replaceFirst("\\)","").toList
res10: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, (, d, e, (, ))

scala>
```

Comment: Also a good way of doing it. Turns out the problem with my code was far more basic :).